# Reading integers from Excel using oledb

Tags: c#, excel

I am using oledb to read data from an excel file and store it in a dataset.
My excel file contents are like as follows:

```
0    0    somestring somestring
500  200  somestring somestring
```

When i checked the contents of my data set, the values of Columns 1 & 2 are not stored as integers but rather as DateTime values.

How will I make it be stored as integer values instead of DateTime?

Comment: UPDATE: I searched the net and found this: http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/37/187667.aspx. Apparently, setting IMEX=1 would just ensure that the registry setting is applied. I changed the following registry entries and now it works:
Hkey_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Excel/TypeGuessRows = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding IMEX=1 to your OLEDB connection string?

Comment: Followed up on your answer and found the solution (see update above). tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its a number? Following could be a few options:

1. Right click the columns in excel and change the format to Text/Custom.
2. Look into the NamedRange.FormatConditions Property; change the format the data when you read it from excel, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.formatconditions(VS.80).aspx)
3. Or try deleting an existing format on a range:

that is,

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = this.Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A5") as Excel.Range; 

//delete previous validation rules  
range.Validation.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd party component like [SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) which lets you get the underlying values of cells (with IWorkbook.Worksheets["MySheet"].Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Value) regardless of the cell format, or you can get the formatted result with IRange.Text.

You can see live ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I won SpreadsheetGear LLC